# Create a localstorage for my background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, express, npm

I have a button that randomly generates a background color every time you click it. I want to make it a `localstorage` function so that every time I close or reload the page my last clicked background color remains on the webpage.

```
      var link = document.getElementById("bglink");
      var output = document.getElementById("output");

      link.addEventListener("click", getRandom);

      function getRandom(){

        var newColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);


        var rgbColor = newColor.replace('#','');
        var r = parseInt(rgbColor.substring(0,2), 16);
        var g = parseInt(rgbColor.substring(2,4), 16);
        var b = parseInt(rgbColor.substring(4,6), 16);
        var result = 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';

        document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
        output.textContent = newColor + " - " + result;


      }

              $("#bglink").click(function () {
    var bgcolor = document.body.style.backgroundColor; 
    localStorage.setItem("bgcolor", document.body.style.backgroundColor);
    alert('Background colour ' + bgcolor + ' saved in localStorage');
});
```

On reload, the page should be set to last color that was set when clicking the button.

Comment: Did you look into localStorage.getItem ? you can check if the color exists and if it does then you can apply it. This should be the first step in your logic. The rest looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add this to check if `bgColor` is set when the document is ready and set the background color.

This should be all you need:

```js
$(function() {
  let bgColor = localStorage.getItem('bgcolor');
  if (bgColor) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
  }
});
```

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Just add this at the top of your file:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem("bgcolor") || "#FFF"; 
//White is default color if no saved color
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple way to save background color to local storage.

HTML

```
<input type="color" id="colorID" oninput="changeColor()">
```

JavaScript

```
function changeColor() { 
  var userColor = document.getElementById('colorID').value;
  localStorage.setItem('storedValue', document.body.style.backgroundColor = userColor);
}

if(localStorage.storedValue) {
  document.getElementById('colorID').value = localStorage.storedValue;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.storedValue;
}
```

---

**CodePen Demo**
https://codepen.io/joshstovall/pen/PrJveQ